# Memorization in computer

Tags: memory-management, location

I looked up registers and memory locations and I found out that a memory location holds 8 bit data while a register can hold up to 64 bit data.
So my question is, how do you memorize a register into a single memory location if the memory location, as you've already noticed, is not big enough? How exactly do you transfer registers data to memory locations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The "memory location" of an object is the location of its **first byte**.

It is not implied that the entire object resides in that one byte.  A 64 bit register, stored in memory verbatim, would occupy the byte at that location **and** the 7 bytes that immediately follow that location.